# For-Loop with JavaScript, got 1 inc number that not in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript. I am trying to make a for-loop, I am looking to get an output with the numbers from 1 to 20 each on a new line with the corresponding string attached to it. But, the output is showing number 21. Any advice?

This is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h3>Soal No. 2</h3>
        <div id="jawaban2"></div>
        <script>
            var jawaban2;
            for (var jawaban2 = 1; jawaban2 <= 20; jawaban2++) {
                if (jawaban2 % 2 === 0) {
                    document.write(jawaban2 + " = Berkualitas" + ("<br/>"))
                } else if (jawaban2 % 3 === 0) {
                    document.write(jawaban2 + " = I Love Koding" + ("<br/>"))
                } else {
                    document.write(jawaban2 + " = Santai" + ("<br/>"))
                }
            }
            console.log(jawaban2);
            document.getElementById("jawaban2").innerHTML = jawaban2
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: The last thing that happens is that the variable reaches the value 21, causing the loop to end.

Comment: You are incrementing `jabmwan2` at the end of each pass through the loop, including the final pass.

Comment: @pointy so how can i remove the value 21? thank you.

Comment: In the last iteration. when the `jawaban2` is 20, it gets incremented by 1 before the loop ends. thus after the for loop ends, the value of jawaban2 is 21. 
Change `for (var jawaban2 = 1; jawaban2 <= 20; jawaban2++)` to `for (var jawaban2 = 1; jawaban2 < 20; jawaban2++)`

Comment: @haloawan: "Remove" from where, specifically?  If you don't want to write that value to `id="jawaban2"` element then just remove the line of code that does that.

Comment: The "21" is being printed by that last `console.log()`. If you don't want that to be printed, take the `console.log()` out.

Comment: @david remove the value 21 from the output, (please run the snippet above, its edited just now)

Comment: @pointy not working sir.

Comment: @haloawan what are you trying to achieve really? What output do you expect and where?

Comment: @goranstoyanov I want the output is 1-20 with the existing string that is in the `div= jawaban2`

Comment: Well taking out a `console.log()` call will certainly discontinue logging the value. If you want the `<div>` to show "20" just put "20" in it in the first place. The question really does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @pointy sorry sir, my english is not that good. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @haloawan check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h3>Soal No. 2</h3>
        <div id="jawaban2"></div>
        <script>
            var content = "";
            for (var jawaban2 = 1; jawaban2 <= 20; jawaban2++) {
                if (jawaban2 % 2 === 0) {
                    content += jawaban2 + " = Berkualitas" + "<br/>";
                } else if (jawaban2 % 3 === 0) {
                    content += jawaban2 + " = I Love Koding" + "<br/>";
                } else {
                    content += jawaban2 + " = Santai" + "<br/>";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("jawaban2").innerHTML = content
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: So i need to make a new var, i get it now. Thank you for your time, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
for (let jawaban2 = 1; jawaban2 <= 20; jawaban2++) {

    if (jawaban2 % 2 === 0) {
        document.write(jawaban2 + " = Berkualitas" + ("<br/>"))
    } else if (jawaban2 % 3 === 0) {
        document.write(jawaban2 + " = I Love Koding" + ("<br/>"))
    } else {
        document.write(jawaban2 + " = Santai" + ("<br/>"))
    }

    if(jawaban2 === 20) {
        document.getElementById("jawaban2").innerHTML = jawaban2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last iteration (`jawaban2 += 1`) is executed and `jawaban2` now has value 21. The loop re-enters, an now the value reaches the case `jawaban2 <= 20`. So the loop is ended. But `jawaban2` is already executed. That's why printing `jawaban2` after the loop shows 21.

You can declare `jawaban2` within the loop (`for (let jawaban2 = 1; ...`).

If you need `jawaban2` after the loop however and you want its value to be the maximum of the loop (20), you should first subtract 1 from it before further use.

Or you can use variable scope ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)), something like:

```js
let jawaban2 = 20;

for (let jawaban2 = 1; jawaban2 <= 20; jawaban2 += 1) {
  //                                   ^ for clarity
  if (jawaban2 % 2 === 0) {
      console.log(jawaban2 + " = Berkualitas")
  } else if (jawaban2 % 3 === 0) {
      console.log(jawaban2 + " = I Love Koding")
  } else {
      console.log(jawaban2 + " = Santai")
  }
}
// scope of jawaban2 within the loop is local
// for the loop, so outer jawaban2 is still 20
console.log(jawaban2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```